# Nodemon keep restarting child pig keep changing

Tags: javascript, node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4Ho8.png)[image]

I didn't make any changes but`nodemon` keeps changing.

Why is happening?

Thanks

Comment: As you can see, your file `model/video.js` changes when your app starts. You should investigate in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your code must have changed some files which are under the watch of nodemon. And as nodemon detect the changes it restarts itself. You should try to ignore unnecessary files by.

> `nodemon --ignore 'filename/pattren'`

Comment: don't forget to include your app.js i.e 
nodemon --ignore 'filename/pattren' --verbose app.js

Comment: I think it's mongodb problem, every request from node, it create a new connection, thus failed, i'm confused what happened

Answer (score 0):

Just to complete the @mehta-rohan's answer, you can add a JSON file to ignore several files/patterns, like this:

```
// nodemon.js at the root of your project
{
    "restartable": "rs",
    "ignore": [
        "server/**/*.js",
    ],
    "verbose": false
}
```